# Can't connect React App to .Net Core API, Post method isnt even called

Tags: .net, reactjs, api, asp.net-core

so I can't find out why i can't do a post request from my React app to my .NET Core API. Get requests work just fine.

My React code:

```
 onCreateEmployee = () => {
let empInfo = {
  Id: this.refs.Id.value,
  Name: this.refs.Name.value,
  Location: this.refs.state.value,
  Salary: this.refs.Salary.value,
};

fetch("https://localhost:44371/api/Employee", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify(empInfo),
})
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then((res) => {
    if (res)
      this.setState({ message: "New employee is created Successfully" });
  });
```

My .NET Core Post method:

```
public bool Post(Employee employee)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=DESKTOP-D0N7K1B\SQLEXPRESS; database=ReactAppDB; Integrated Security = True");
        string query = "insert into EmployeeInfo values(@Id,@Name,@Loc,@Sal)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", employee.Id));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", employee.Name));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Loc", employee.Location));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Sal", employee.Salary));
        conn.Open();
        int noOfRowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return noOfRowsAffected > 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

Cors is enabled and works as the successfull get requests suggests. The post method isnt even called somehow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Dot Net Core are you using?
Try adding `[FromBody]` inside your Http Post method:

```
public bool Post([FromBody] Employee employee)
{
     // implementation
}
```

You can also send the same request with the same body through Postman to check for errors and error code.

In addition you should never put you connection string inside your method function.
you can check [Getting Started with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli) for more information on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to decorate your method with `[HttpPost]` attribute. (explicit is better)

Also, you want to specify `[FromBody]` attribute for your request object as @charbel specified above.

Apart from this you can try to view what routes you currently have registered using action descriptors:

```
public class YourController : Controller {
        private readonly IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider _provider;

        public YourController(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider provider) {
          _provider = provider;
        }

        // You mentioned that you have a GET method that works as expected
        // You can add the code in there or you can create another route/method in that controller
        [HttpGet("routes")]
        public IActionResult GetRoutes() {
            var routes = _provider.ActionDescriptors.Items.Select(x => new { 
               Action = x.RouteValues["Action"], 
               Controller = x.RouteValues["Controller"], 
               Name = x?.AttributeRouteInfo?.Name, 
               Template = x?.AttributeRouteInfo?.Template,
               HttpMethods = x?.ActionConstraints?.OfType<HttpMethodActionConstraint>().FirstOrDefault()?.HttpMethods
            }).ToList();
            return Ok(routes);
        }
      }
```

If you want to always have a way to inspect your routes, I'd recommend adding a middleware and creating a route that invokes it in the following manner: https://gist.github.com/McKabue/b5caf25f9862b2488a9fa7898e22e86e

Or adding a swagger middleware: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio